# How to convert a value from JSON like "01" into a month name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

How we convert "01" month to January and "02" February like that all the months.

example I am getting value from JSON as "01" but i need to print the value as "January" and as "02" February. can you please help how we can do in javascript?

Comment: The answer to your actual question is no - there's no built-in list of month names, you have to make your own.

Comment: I don't see the effort you put into trying to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

```
alert(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
 "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
 "November", "December"][myNumberFromJSON - 1]);
```

Comment: wont the return value be a string??... `[parseInt(myNumberFromJson) - 1]`

Comment: JS will convert it in order to subtract 1, no?

Comment: not sure.. i'm no expert but,its not good coding practice.. best if you handle it..

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin, exactly, and it's safer than using `parseInt` without the radix argument, for example: `'08' - 1` is obviously `7`, but `parseInt('08') -1` is `-1` ('08' is treated implicitly as an octal number)

Comment: @CMS , dint know that.. thought that its best to handle such responses than letting js convert it which ever form is appropriate..

Comment: @VivekChandra Why pretend it's a strictly typed language when it isn't?

Answer (score 2):

```
function getMonthFromNumber(num){
  var months = "January February March April May June July August September October  November December";
  num = Math.abs(parseInt(num, 10));  
  if(isNaN(num)){
    throw new Error(num + ' is not a valid number');
  } else if (num > 12){
    throw new Error('No month matches ' + num + '. Value must be less than 13.');
  }
  return  months.split(' ')[num - 1];
}

alert(getMonthFromNumber(10));
```

Comment: Why have the months as a string that must be split when they could be an array to begin with?

Comment: Style preference - to me it's easier to read and quicker to type. Where performance was critical, I'd create an array from the start.